# Having Issues With Rewrites In .htaccess including 404 & more

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Go easy on me I'm new to making changes to .htaccess files. I have the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Exclude rewriting for specific file types and existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif)$

# Redirections
RewriteRule ^search$ search.php [L]
RewriteRule ^our-story$ our-story.html [L]
RewriteRule ^blog$ blog.php
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.html
RewriteRule ^faq$ faq.html
RewriteRule ^pricing$ pricing.html
RewriteRule ^register$ register.php
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php
RewriteRule ^dashboard$ dashboard.php
RewriteRule ^404$ 404.html

# 404 Page
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

The questions and problems are as followed.

1. The 404 doesn't work when the 404 isn't in home directory example https://link.com/fakelink will go to 404 correctly but https://link.com/direct/fakelink will not go to 404 correctly.
2. Is there a better way to handle Redirections without having to manually do each one like I am currently doing?

Another thing I don't know how to do I have a php file that looks like (https://link.com/list.php?url=city-location/listing-name) I want it to rewrite to https://link.com/city-location/listing-name how can I go about doing this?

All help is appreciate!

Comment: _"Another thing"_ - for that, I'd like to refer you to [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained) - read up on a bit of the basics, and then make an attempt.

Comment: 2. you can combine multiple of those rules into one, `RewriteRule ^(search|blog|...)$ $1.php [L]`, and the same for the `.html` files.

Comment: RewriteConds affect only the immediately following rule, so the way they are used here makes rather little sense. They affect the `^search$` rule only, and that does neither match an existing file, nor does it have any of those suffixes.

Comment: 1. not sure what causes that, but I would suspect it probably has to do with that last rule, `RewriteRule ^404$ 404.html`. Try and remove that. (There should be no real need to have a "pretty" URL for your error document, no one is expected to _deliberately_ request `/404` in the first place, right?)